# Chef Issue bootstrapping windows VM using winrm over https using self signed certificate

Tags: windows, chef-infra, bootstrapping, winrm

Chef Server(RHEL 6.5): 11.16.4

Windows endpoint: Windows 2008

The bootstrapping works fine over http (`with winrm config allowUnEncrypeted = true and basic auth = true`).

Now we are trying same thing over https(`but with basic auth = false and AllowUnEncrypted = false`)

The self signed certificate is generated(with private key) and I've verified telnet over port 443.

To check connectivity, I've run the following command from my terminal (windows 7),

```
winrs -r:https://<fqdn Of windows EP>:443 -u:administrator -p:password_1 ipconfig
```

which works fine after adding the self signed certificate under trusted root certification authorities.

Error while bootstrapping from chef server:

```
  [root@v-ng25-rhel6u5-tpm722 ~]# knife bootstrap windows winrm v-ngibm71tpm7222k8.example.co.in -x Administrator -P 'password_1' -p 443 --bootstrap-version '11.16.4-1'

Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate


ERROR: No response received from remote node after 1.84 minutes, giving up.
ERROR: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Ideally if the winrs command works(meaning there is no issue with the self signed cert generation and listener config), so should this.

Any help/pointers is much appreciated.

---

Updates:

1. Taken care of removing spaces in thumbprint while creating listener
2. `knife ssl check` is able to verify certificate
3. Gave the `--no-ssl-peer-verification` option a try at link [link]https://github.com/gswallow/knife-windows/commit/d04c835cfff1260017b91a799168e90b931cad6a
4. The env var `SSL_CERT_FILE` points to `/opt/chef-server/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` which contains the remote machine certificate
5. Tried an adhoc suggestion to add certificate to keystore at `/opt/opscode/embedded/jre/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Issue still persists.

---

UPDATE:

This is what worked,

Edit file

`/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/knife-windows-0.8.0/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap_windows_winrm.rb`

and add line,

`winrm.config[:no_ssl_peer_verification] = true`

Edit file

`/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/knife-windows-0.8.0/lib/chef/knife/winrm.rb`

and add line,

`session_opts[:no_ssl_peer_verification] = true if config.has_key?(:no_ssl_peer_verification)`

It still gives the self signed error but atleast it bootstraps

OUTPUT:

`Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
tpm72-win2K8R2.example.com .
tpm72-win2K8R2.example.com Response received.
Remote node responded after 0.0 minutes.
Bootstrapping Chef on tpm72-win2K8R2.example.com
at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
tpm72-win2K8R2.example.com "Rendering "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-22620-1423038641.bat" chunk 1"
at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
tpm72-win2K8R2.example.com "Rendering "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-22620-1423038641.bat" chunk 2"`

Comment: Last resort coming to my head, try over https with the same parameters as http (to see if it's only a certificate problem or an authentification problem added to a certificate warning)

Comment: @Tensibai Error remains the same keeping paramters same as they were for http ( `winrm config allowUnEncrypeted = true and basic auth = true` ).

I'll try this to see if it helps [link] http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#selfsigned-openssl

Comment: Just reviewed one of your link (the 3) Seems there's a config option for the CA cert file: `winrm.config[:ca_trust_file] = Chef::Config[:knife][:ca_trust_file] if Chef::Config[:knife][:ca_trust_file]` So you may try adding `knife[:ca_trust_file] = "/opt/chef-server/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"` to your knife.rb file.

Comment: @Tensibai Updated a workaround. Seems to bypass the error.

Comment: thanks for the update, it will probably help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Knife command use openssl lib, which has no clue about your windows certificate store but use it's own.

You have to add the remote machine certificate to the cacert.pem file of the ruby stack in `<path to chef install>\embedded\ssl\certs\cacert.pem` )

You may have to add an environment variable named `SSL_CERT_FILE` to point to this file for other tools too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
The SSL_CERT_FILE is set to /opt/chef-server/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

I have tried adding the remote machine certificate to cacert.pem at 2 locations 
`/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`
`/opt/chef-server/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`

And just so as not to have any ambiguity, by add I mean that I copied the contents of the remote machine certificate to the end of cacert.pem file at both locations. The remote machine certiificate content were in form of "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and so on  -----END CERTIFICATE-----"

Comment: @Ivan Unsure of the result of your comment, do you still have SSL errors ? (quick link to the doc with exemples for domain authentification: http://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_windows.html )

Comment: Yes the error is still present. While creating listener, ive taken care of removing the spaces as mentioned in the link you've pasted, and the port is also correct( as evident by the winrs successful result triggered from a windows machine). Output of knife ssl check is positive(after using knife ssl fetch to add it to trusted_certs). Please let me know if I could verify anything else.

Comment: @Ivan I really think the basic auth can't be bypassed from a linux box, I'll have a look at the code if I can. Meanwhile you may try bootstrapping from you workstation (configuring knife on it, etc.)

Comment: Few updates on trials
I tried the --node-ssl-verify-mode option(just to check) in bootstrap only to find it does not go with knife bootstrap windows winrm
Tried an adhoc suggestion to add certificate to keystore at /opt/opscode/embedded/jre/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Tried the option mentioned at link 
[link]https://github.com/gswallow/knife-windows/commit/d04c835cfff1260017b91a799168e90b931cad6a

Comment: Right now its a test env, the workstation resides on the same machine as chef server(and bootstrapping works over http as already stated)
Although if you mean that basicAuth must be true, I've given bootstrapping a try with basicAuth = true and AllowUnencrypted = false with same error.

Comment: I wonder if below difference in outputs have any significance and whether openssl should automatically trust(since the remote machine's certificate is added in /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem with SSL_CERT_FILE pointing to it )
            openssl s_client -showcerts -connect WindowsEPHostname:5986 
Gives: Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

      openssl s_client -showcerts -connect WindowsEPHostname:5986 -CApath /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs 
Gives: Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Comment: @Ivan please update your question by editing it instead of adding comments They're not great for code formatting. Your last SSL test has been made without `SSL_CERT_FILE` pointing to the cacert.pem (this env var has the same effect as `-CApath` option.